# Passing over NoneType attributes in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml

I am parsing an XML feed from Google using beautifulstonesoup and python, and it works great. I am also creating a csv and uploading it to Google Docs, which works fine as well. The problem is when I come across an empty text attribute in the xml, the parser just stops. It is not a problem now, because all of the attributes have data, but the first time they don't, it will break.

The code:

```py
import atom
import gdata.auth
import gdata.contacts
import gdata.contacts.client
import gdata.docs.service
import gdata.docs.data
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup as Soup
import csv

email = 'admin@domain.com'
password = 'password'
domain = 'domain.com'

ms_client = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
gd_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient(domain=domain)
gd_client.ClientLogin(email, password, 'profileFeedAPI')
ms_client.ClientLogin(email, password, 'peopleCSVupload')

profiles_feed = gd_client.GetProfilesFeed('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/domain.com/full?max-results=300')

soup = Soup(str(profiles_feed), selfClosingTags=['ns0:category','ns3:status', 'ns0:link','ns1:email'])

a = soup.findAll('ns0:entry')
f = open('C:\\people.csv', 'wb')

writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar =' ')

for entry in a:
    writer.writerow([entry.find('ns1:familyname').text + ',' + entry.find('ns1:givenname').text + ',' + entry.find('ns1:fullname').text + ',' + entry.find('ns1:orgtitle').text + ',' + entry.find('ns1:orgdepartment').text + ',' + entry.find('ns1:orgname').text + ',' + entry.find('ns1:email',primary=True)['address']])

f.close()

ms = gdata.data.MediaSource(file_path="C:\\people.csv", content_type=gdata.docs.service.SUPPORTED_FILETYPES['CSV'])
csv_entry = ms_client.Upload(ms, "People File")
```

I know I could do this:

```py
for entry in a:
    if entry.find('ns1:orgtitle') != None:
        print entry.find('ns1:orgtitle').text
    elif entry.find('ns1:orgtitle') == None:
        print('')
    if entry.find('ns1:familyname') != None:
        print entry.find('ns1:familyname').text
    elif entry.find('ns1:familyname') == None:
        print('')
        etc...
```

But it is very long, and I don't know how to concentrate the data to appear on one row. Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can wrap the find like this:

```
def findnonempty(entry, arg):
    result = entry.find(arg):
    if result:
        return result.text
    else:
        return ""
```

the you can either do the 7 calls one after each other or you can use map(), like

```
tags = ['ns1:familyname', 'ns1:givenname', ... ] # your tags
s = map(lambda tag: findnonempty(entry, tag), tags)
"".join(s)
```

Comment: Beyer sorry for looking at this so late, I was away for the weekend. This is a fantastic solution, but I only have one question. The last item, the email address is in a attribute, not a text field. How would I be able to extract that data?

Comment: Nevermind, I just declared a variable t that is entry.find('ns1:email',primary=True)['address'], and did s.append(t) in the for entry in a block, thanks again for this.

Answer (score 1):

At first I didn't see why you thought it would break...you didn't have an "offending" data snippet. BeautifulSoup will gladly return an empty string.

At the END of your "have to scroll over there to see it" line it's finally clear that you are (as you did say in your intro) looking for an attribute.

```
entry.find('ns1:email',primary=True)['address']
```

The empty attribute will not return as silently as an empty text node (e.g. `entry.find('ns1:familyname').text`).

Never fear, just substitute the `['address']` notation with `.get('address','')` and it will return an empty string if empty rather than throw a KeyError

Comment: The XML feed won't produce an email entry without the address attribute being present. It happens when a text field like OrgName is empty, because I am parsing for a field that has a NoneType value.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to encapsulate the value-getting and printing into functions.

```
def find(entry, spec, default=None):
    value = entry.find(spec)
    return default if value is None else value.text

def findandprint(entry, spec, default=None, newline=True):
    value = find(entry, spec, default)
    if value is not None:    # if we still don't have a value even after
        print value,         # considering default, don't print anything
        if newline:
            print
```

Then you can just:

```
for entry in a:
    findandprint(entry, 'ns1:orgtitle',   default="")
    findandprint(entry, 'ns1:familyname', default="")
```

If you have a lot of attributes, and want to handle them all the same, then iterate over those too:

```
for entry in a:
    for attribute in ('ns1:orgtitle', 'ns1:familyname', ...):
        findandprint(entry, attribute, default="")
```