# How do I ignore a BeautifulSoup AttributeError/Continue on Exception

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have built a web scraper with Python and Beautiful Soup

Sometimes certain elements exist, sometimes they don't. I have a ton of them. It doesn't really make sense for me to set up a custom exception for each "find" and/or "find_all"

I just want to ignore the errors so that my scraper will not halt on exception. Here's the error output from my terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "listing-scraper.py", line 80, in <module>
    'engine_size':soup.find("span",{"id":"infoEngine Size"}).contents[0],
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'
```

How can I just continue?

Here's a snip of my source code- so you can see how it's set up. (Please be nice, I am new to Python)

```
    dealer_info = {
        'name':dealer_box.find("h4").contents[0],
        'address':dealer_address,
        'phone':re.sub(r'[^\d.]+','',soup.find("div",{"class":"PhoneNumber"}).contents[0]),
        'logo':soup.find("div",{"class":"dealerLogo"}).img['src'],
        'about':dealer_about,
        'website':website,
        'video':dealer_video
    }

    thumbnails = soup.find("div",{"class":"imageThumbs"}).find_all('img')
    dealer_thumbnails = []

    for thumbnail in thumbnails:
        dealer_thumbnails.append(thumbnail['src'])

    motorcycle = {
        'insert_date':time.time() * 1000,
        'year':soup.find("span",{"id":"infoYear"}).contents[0],
        'make':soup.find("span",{"id":"infoMake"}).contents[0],
        'model':soup.find("span",{"id":"infoModel"}).contents[0],
        'type':soup.find("span",{"id":"infoType"}).contents[0],
        'location':soup.find("span",{"id":"infoLocation"}).contents[0],
        'color':soup.find("span",{"id":"infoColor"}).contents[0],
        'engine_size':soup.find("span",{"id":"infoEngine Size"}).contents[0],
        'description':description,
        'price':soup.find("h3",{"class":"askingPriceNumber"}).contents[1],
        'thumbnails':dealer_thumbnails,
        'dealer_info':dealer_info
    }

    listing.update(motorcycle)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing over NoneType attributes in BeautifulSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201032/passing-over-nonetype-attributes-in-beautifulsoup)

Comment: What's wrong with using a `try..except` block?

Answer (score 2):

Consider something like:

```
def getcontents(item, index):
    if item is None:
        return None
    return item.contents[index]

motorcycle = {
        'insert_date':time.time() * 1000,
        'year':getcontents(soup.find("span",{"id":"infoYear"}), 0),
        ...
```

Generally, you shouldn't be ignoring the exception if you can avoid causing it in the first place.